# Kentico Product Options: enabled backend but hidden frontend

Tags: kentico

I am fairly new to Kentico and I am not 100% sure how to prevent a product option from displaying on the frontend website, but keeping it enabled in the backend so the system admins can still place orders using the option.

For example

CMSDesk > Tools > Ecommerce > Product Options > Edit an option which has child options

Eg, there are three child options, two of which I want displayed to the user on the website, but only one of them I want to hide from the end user and ONLY allow the Administrator to have access to the option...

Has anyone ever had the need for this feature before?  If so, how did you accomplish it?

Thanks

Michelle

Answer (score 0):

Please find my answer on our official Kentico forum:

[forum link][1]

Our forums are more often monitored,than stackoverflow, so I would suggest to continue our discussion there ;)

Regards,
Boris,
Kentico

---

UPDATE:

If the link should be invalidated, here is the full answer:

Regrettably, this can't be achieved right out of the box. you will have to customize the control displaying the options a bit. You need to modify the following method:

LoadProductOptions()

in the file \CMSModules\Ecommerce\Controls\ProductOptions\ShoppingCartItemSelector.ascx.cs. There are the product options loaded and displayed on the live site. you would have to check if the current user is a global administrator and skip the processing of some field, if he is not. A second approach is to change the OptionCategoryInfoProvider.GetSKUOptionCategories method by overriding it with a custom e-commerce handler. More information on this topic can be found under the links below:

Relevant links can be found in the forum post, since I can't post more than 2 links in a post.

Here is a sample of an provider object override:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

using CMS.WorkflowEngine;
using CMS.SettingsProvider;
using CMS.Ecommerce;
using CMS.EcommerceProvider;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
[MyHandlers]
public partial class CMSModuleLoader {
    private class MyHandlers: CMSLoaderAttribute {

        public override void Init() {
            OrderInfoProvider.ProviderObject = new MyEcommerceCustomHandler();

            WorkflowEvents.Approve.After += WorkflowEvents_Publish_Handler;
        }

        private static void WorkflowEvents_Publish_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //insert custom code here
        }
    }

    public class MyEcommerceCustomHandler: OrderInfoProvider {
        protected override string GetInvoiceInternal(int orderId) {
            return base.GetInvoiceInternal(orderId);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also add a custom field to the product option table to indicate, if the field should be displayed on the live site or not.

Comment: Could you at least summarize your answer here, so that people don't have to visit your site to see it? Also, that protects against this link going away at some point in the future.

Comment: @Boris, you refer to links - but there arent any in the answer. Do they still exist?